# How to convert Spring MVC to android project using PhoneGap?

Tags: android, spring, spring-mvc, cordova

I didn't find any tutorial in the internet that can shed light on creating android project from spring MVC project using phone gap.

I started with a sample [mvc application](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mobile-samples/tree/master/lite-device-resolver), need to create an android client out of it. Can anyone help me with it.

Comment: Spring MVC is a servlet web application. As far as I know there is no servlet container on Android.

Comment: Also, PhoneGap is a client UI tool, used to allow developers to code their phone application using HTML5 and web standards.

Comment: I mean to use spring rest, which can be call by plain html and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Rest services are transferring data over http, so you can use json or xml with ajax to call Rest services in your phonegap app and server side it will be spring MVC. i am sure the following link can help you http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/spring-mvc-easy-rest-based-json-services-with-responsebody.html

Comment: I think the problem with the answer "use the responsebody" is that Spring MVC Controller methods that have been created for websites tend to return Strings as opposed to responsebody. It's more relevant if there is a way to use the existing infrastructure as opposed to having to create a new one